# JSONArrayRequest and PHP pair not working

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am creating class which should send `JSONArrayRequest` using volley with specific params, then find `mysql` rows which equals these params and send it back. I wrote simple `mysql` function which receive `POST` params and Java method which send and receive `JSONObjects`. But it isn't working and I receive nothing.

This is my **PHP** file called `details.php`. It receive parameters from my Android App and send back an array.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php'
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$path= $_POST["path"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM modx_ms2_product_files WHERE path = $path") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product ["file"] = $row["file"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($json_response, $product);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($json_response);

    $conn->close();
}
```

This is my method `getArray()`, which send request and receive response:

```
 public void getarray() {
     String path = "1578/";
     final String URL = "http://myurl.io/details.php";
     HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
     params.put("path", path);

     JsonArrayRequest customarray = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,new JSONObject(params),new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
             if (response.length() > 0) {
                 // Parsing json
                 for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                     try {
                         JSONObject Obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                         pics pic = new pics();
                         pic.setFile(Obj.getString("file"));
                         Log.i("cmon", Obj.getString("file"));
                         pics.add(pic);
                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }    
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

         }
     });
     AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(customarray);
 }
```

This is my `modx_ms2_product_files` table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UqfK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq7JZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `StringRequest`? For some reason when i used `JsonArrayRequest` i didn't get any response back from the server. If you decide to create a `StringRequest` you could convert your response to a `JSONArray` like this:

```
StringRequest get = new StringRequest(Method.POST, URL, new Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jObj = myArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // get your data here

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Then of course add your request to the request queue.

Comment: No its working great. I guess something wrong with my PHP

Comment: forgot about this bug. Now I started new project and have sam issue. Yout answer rly helped. Thank you mate!

Comment: Glad i could help you